# Populating HashMaps of HashMap of Objects

Tags: java, object, maps, hashmap

I have code I am working on, but I am having issues populating the HashMap of HashMaps. The declaration goes as thus;

```
HashMap<Games, HashMap<Store, Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<Games, HashMap<Store,   Integer>>();
```

Where `Game` and `Store` are separate object classes, with only a class variable title.

How do I create instances of the objects in the HashMaps and also populate the two hashmaps. Because I need to tag an Integer to the game in a particular store. Whereas there are different stores and different games in each store.

Thanks in Advance

**Edit**

***Games Class***

```
package gameStore;

public class Games {
    private String title;

    public Games(String inTitle){
        setTitle(inTitle);
    }
    private String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    private void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

***Stores Class***

```
package gameStore;

public class LocalStores {
    private String nameOfStore;

    public LocalStores(String inNameOfStore){
        setNameOfStore(inNameOfStore);
    }
    private void setNameOfStore(String nameOfStore){
        this.nameOfStore = nameOfStore;
    }
}
```

Comment: you might provide the code for Games and Store

Comment: It seems, like you could also use database for storing that info. There is a DB included into JDK -- Java DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
void addToMap(Games games, Store store, int value) {
    HashMap<Store,Integer> m = myMap.get(games);
    if (m == null) {
        m = new HashMap<Store,Integer>();
        myMap.put(games, m);
    }
    m.put(store, value);
}
```

UPDATE:

Since Games and Store are both used as keys to a HashMap, I would recommand that you add the hashCode and equals methods:

Games:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return title.hashCode();
}

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Games)) {
        return false;
    }
    Games other = (Games)obj;
    return title.equals(other.title);
}
```

LocalStores:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return nameOfStore.hashCode();
}

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof LocalStores)) {
        return false;
    }
    LocalStores other = (LocalStores)obj;
    return nameOfStore.equals(other.nameOfStore);
}
```

Now, to keep it simple, let's say that each line of your input file contains three fields separated by tabs: the games' title, the store's name, and the integer value. You would read it as follows:

```
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("myfile");
try {
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"); // or another encoding
    try {
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(reader);
        try {
            String line = in.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                String[] fields = line.split("[\\t]");
                if (fields.length == 3) {
                    addToMap(new Games(fields[0]), new LocalStores(fields[1]), Integer.parseInt(fields[2]));
                }
                line = in.readLine();
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
} finally {
    stream.close();
}
```

Comment: Hello Maurice, can you please explain what you are trying to say?

Comment: this code will map an integer to a couple (Games,Store). The integer can then be retrieved by doing myMap.get(games).get(store).

Comment: Okay.. But I am thinking of populating the Objects here... To populate the objects with strings from a file... as the title... and then create instances of the objects into the Map before assigning the generated random Integer to assign... then query from within the HashMap. Can you please be descriptive about this...

Comment: As someone commented, you didn't provide the code for Games and Store. Difficult to know how to read these things...

Comment: Hi Maurice, I have included the classes

Comment: Hi Maurice, thanks so much. For the Hashcode, do you mean 'return title.hashCode()'? 

Also in the code;

' public boolean equals(Object obj) {
     if (!(obj instanceof Store)) {
         return false;
     }
     Store other = (Games)obj;
     return nameOfStore.equals(other.nameOfStore);'

do you mean LocalStores instead of Store? and if that be the case, LocalStores other = (Games)obj generates an error with (Games)obj stating a type mismatch...

Comment: Okay... So you mean I should cast it? But they are of same type of Object.. why do I still need to cast it?

Comment: Because we are comparing the title or the nameOfStore. Object has neither.

Comment: Meaning it should be something like this right? 'LocalStores other = (LocalStores)obj;'

Comment: Hi Maurice, in the addToMap method, the myMap would be the map that holds all three together right? I really do not understand the series of populating the map as described in the addToMap but I will go over it with my pen to get it straight. Also If i need to query from it I will also do same loop within a loop of each map.

Comment: Also, wht the equation

'HashMap<Store,Integer> m = myMap.get(games);'

Comment: Hi Maurice, Please i am still having issues wih the declaration of the myMap you declared...

Comment: Here is what I have done so far... 

http://pastebin.com/kWVkZQtD

If you can explain the declaration maybe I can proceed.

Comment: Can I get the key from the Hashmap given the value?